# optimizing VHDL code

Tags: vhdl

I have made this VHDL code for writing to a USB-chip.

It all runs inside a case statement, where each operation (write, read, ect.) is implemented.

The two write register sections below are equal, only different by the address and data.

Can this be simplified using a procedure or something?

```
            -------- WRITE REGISTER ---------
            when s10 =>
                -- Txd Cmd
                txdata(7 downto 6) <=  "10";        -- CMD = register write
                txdata(5 downto 0) <=  "000100";    -- address
                state := s11;
            when s11 => 
                -- write reg
                if nxt = '1' then
                    txdata <= X"45";    -- output on clock rising edge when nxt is high
                    stp <= '1';                     
                    state := s12;
                end if;
            when s12 =>
                stp <= '0';                             
                txdata <= "00000000";       -- idle                 
                state := s20;

            -------- WRITE REGISTER ---------
            when s20 =>
                -- Txd Cmd
                txdata(7 downto 6) <=  "10";        -- CMD = register write
                txdata(5 downto 0) <=  "110101";    -- address
                state := s21;
            when s21 => 
                -- write reg
                if nxt = '1' then
                    txdata <= X"04";                                            
                    stp <= '1';                     
                    state := s22;
                end if;
            when s22 =>
                stp <= '0';                             
                txdata <= "00000000";       -- idle                 
                state := s30;
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You will make the code much more complicated than it needs to be. Do you have problem with the code? Do you need to optimize it in any way or you just want to do it because....?

Comment: Just because i'm repeating my self, so if I need to change something in write sequence, I will have to change it in all the write sequences.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Design VHDL state machine for initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937254/design-vhdl-state-machine-for-initialization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a procedure.  Is this not what you asked here already?

[Design VHDL state machine for initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937254/design-vhdl-state-machine-for-initialization)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest for you  to use a register for address and data values. Then you have to describe the actual writing only one, everything else is just a change of the registercontents. That could be done in a state before you start your writing...